# Como rodar múltiplas funções onEdit no mesmo script (google sheets)?

Tags: script, google-sheets

Eu tentei de várias maneiras e nenhuma funcionou.

Quero uma função que quando alguém digitar algo, o conteúdo da célula automaticamente fica todo maiúsculo e sem acentos.

E.g.: se eu digitar "áéîõÂÃüÚ", isso imediatamente vira "AEIOAAUU".

O que já tentei:

1. mudar a letra com acento para uma letra sem e depois deixar tudo maiúsculo, tudo no mesmo onEdit;
2. separar as funções em diferentes onEdit, no mesmo script;
3. um onEdit que chamas as funções em outros scripts.

Este é meu código:

```
function onEdit(e){
  try{
    myA(e);
    myE(e);
    myUpper(e);
  }
  catch(e){
    if(e){}}
}

function myFunction(){
  var app= SpreadsheetApp;
  var targetSheet= app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  onEdit();
}
```

As funções "myA", "myE" and "myUpper" estão, cada uma, em um script separado e elas são:

```
function myUpper(e) {
   e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
}

function myE(e) {
  e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(new RegExp("[[éèêëÉÈÊË]", 'g'),"E"));
}

function myA(e) {
  e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(new RegExp("[[áàâäãÁÀÂÄÃ]", 'g'),"A"));
}
```

Rodando o código, apenas a função "myE" funciona. Ou seja, apenas as letras "e" com acento se tornam "E".

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi com o seguinte código:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var value = e.value;
  var range = e.range;
  value = value.replace(new RegExp("[[éèêëÉÈÊË]", 'g'),"E");
  value = value.replace(new RegExp("[[áàâäãÁÀÂÄÃ]", 'g'),"A");
  value = value.toUpperCase();
  range.setValue(value);
}
```